# how to Count the number of occurrences of a character in a string but not one of them?

Tags: javascript

I have a string and i need to check number of occurrence of character

```
   var obj = "str one,str two,str three,str four";
```

i am trying some thing like this :-

```
console.log(("str one,str two,str three,str four".match(new RegExp("str", "g")) || []).length);
```

**It returns 4**

this is working fine,

But my condition is i don't have to check **str three** from that string, so output should be **3**

Help me to find the solution of this issue.

Thanks

Comment: You want all ocurrences of str[number] but str3?

Comment: yes but not for str3

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande  I just update my question, can you please take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var string = "str1,str2,str3,str4";
var count = (string.match(/str[0-24-9]/g) || []).length;
console.log(count); //3

var string = "str one,str two,str three,str four";
var count = (string.match(/str (?!three)/g) || []).length;
console.log(count); //3
```

**(?!three)** - Negative lookahead `(?!)`, which specifies a group that cannot match after the main expression.

Comment: I just update my question, can you please take a look

Comment: Great thanks for your help it works fine but what if i change like that (/str (?!three)/g) to (/ (?!three) str/g)

Comment: What is your actual string, because with the one you've given my regex does work as you can see in the example ;)

Comment: my actual string  is PICKED, NOT PICKED,PICKED, INSTALL ;; so i need only PICKED count.

Comment: I see, that's why I said don't forget to post your actual string since a regex maybe completely different ;)

Answer (score 0):

Split your string as an array, and then count the number of elements that

1. Are not 'str three'
2. Match your regexp

Something like this?

```
var numMatches = obj.split(',').filter(function(str) {
    return el !== 'str three' && el.match(/str/);
}).length
```

Or if you want to have fun with regexps, you can use a negative look ahead!

```
var numMatches = obj.match(/(?!str three)str/g).length;
```

Comment: I just update my question, can you please take a look